# What is the highest dodge chance I can achieve in game?

Tags: payday-2

Is there a cap for dodge chance in Payday 2, or is can I hit 100% dodge? What is the highest dodge chance I can hit in game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum dodge you can get depends on your current standing/crouching running/walking state:

- 50% standing still
- 65% crouched still
- 75% sprinting

It's also possible to briefly get as high as 90% dodge by sprinting into a crouch but this only has a very brief overlap during which it is active.

This would require wearing the suit with Sprinter aced, Shinobi basic, Duck and Cover aced and Sneaky Bastard aced. For perks go full rogue.

Comment: Does the new burgular perk deck work better for crouching?

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by kalina was correct upon being posted but is no longer relevant due to the skill tree revamp.

Now, dodge chances have been reduced. the 75% chance is now lowered to about a 50% and the standing is 35%, if i recall correctly.

I cannot get the exact values right now, but dodge chances have fallen considerably as of update 100