# How does "Dodge" really work?

Tags: payday-2

This has actually been a burning question I have had for the longest time now. How does the "Dodge" mechanic in Payday 2 really work? To my (vague) knowledge, dodge allows you to basically avoid damage. Essentially, rather than simply increasing the damage you can take, it reduces the damage that you take. However, I still don't understand how it works precisely.

- **For starters, what do the dodge values represent?**

For example, how much better is having 50 Dodge as compared to having 20 Dodge?
Does your amount of dodge represent your percentage chance of dodging a bullets?

- **Secondly, when can you dodge?"**

When do you begin to dodge bullets? It is completely random, where you would dodge random incoming projectiles?

- **Lastly, what can you dodge?**

Are you able to dodge anything? For example, apart from your usual bullets, can you dodge sniper shots, explosive damage or Cloaker hits?

Comment: Since I have three questions, I am not sure if I should be splitting them up. Should I split the above into 3 separate questions?

Comment: I think they all fit quite well into "How does the Dodge mechanic work?", and it's not too broad for a single question.

Comment: I came here because I read "how does doge works" WOW such dissapointment WOW bad reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For starters, what do the dodge values represent?

The dodge value is the chance **in percent** to take no damage at all when hit.

### Secondly, when can you dodge?

You can always dodge.

### Lastly, what can you dodge?

Melee attacks are dodged just like bullets, however the player is always pushed back despite not taking damage.

---

There is a [**very very long** guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=267214370) available in the steam workshop, everything you need can be found there. In your case dodge can be found under Armor stats. (The loading could take a bit because of the length of the guide so dont worry if it wont be loaded as fast as expected)

Answer (score 1):

While I normally don't play dodge builds, I'll answer as best I can:

> what do the dodge values represent?

They are percentage chances to avoid all damage of any attack.

> when can you dodge?

Any time, however the dodge chance is dependent on your stance. See [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197664/what-is-the-highest-dodge-chance-i-can-achieve-in-game) for some examples.

> what can you dodge?

You can dodge all ranged projectiles and the damage from melee attacks. I'm not sure about explosives or cloaker attacks, but I suspect cloaker ninja-kicks aren't actually attacks, but a special action, and thus cannot be dodged.

Source and more info [here](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Armors#Dodge).